# Segmentation Fault in Program that Reads the Last 10 lines From Command Line

Tags: c

I am currently trying to create a program that prints the last 10 lines of another text program that is passed in through the command line. The function read() should read a single line from the text file and then return either the string or NULL, while the main function should keep assigning the output from read() until NULL is assigned.

I have gone through many different versions of this program, but it always ends up causing a segmentation fault. How would I begin to debug the segmentation fault?

I have included the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read(){
   char *line = (char *) malloc (80 * sizeof(char));
   fgets(line,80,stdin);
   if (line != NULL) {
      line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
      return line;
   }
   else {
      free(line);
      return NULL;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int i=0,j,k,l;
   char **arr = (char **) malloc (100 * sizeof(char *));
   for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
      arr[k] = malloc (80 * sizeof(char));
   }

   while(1){
      strcpy(arr[i],read());
      if (arr[i]=NULL) break;
      i++;
      //printf("%s", arr[i]);  //DEBUG
   }

   for (l = 0; l < 100; l++){
      free(arr[l]);
   }
   free(arr);

   for (j = i-11; j < i; j++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to identify WHERE the set fault occurs, and work from there.

Comment: And `malloc` does not need a cast

Comment: Assuming the function works properly you must check its return value for `NULL` *before* passing it to `strcpy`. Also `line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';` will cause havoc if there is no newline (perhaps the last line in the file), see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221). You also have a memory leak in your `read` function. Lastly it is a bad idea to name it `read` because there is a standard library function by that name, which does something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *main*

```
while(1){
  strcpy(arr[i],read());
  if (arr[i]=NULL) break;
```

you never go out of the loop because `arr[i]=NULL` has no reason to be true from *read* (because of an error in *read*), so you write out of *arr* with an undefined behavior (your crash)

You do not well manage the end of file in read :

```
fgets(line,80,stdin);
if (line != NULL) {
```

you need to check the result of *fgets* not if *line* is NULL except to check *malloc* success

not that `line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';` is useless because *fgets* put a final null character, fortunately else how *strlen* can work ?

So *read* can be :

```
char *read(){
  char *line = (char *) malloc (80 * sizeof(char));

   if (line != NULL) {
     if (fgets(line,80,stdin) == NULL) {
       free(line);
       return NULL;
     }
   }

   return line;
}
```

Because read can return a NULL you need to change

```
  strcpy(arr[i],read());
```

and also is why you preallocate the lines while you also allocate in read ? currently you loose the memory allocated each time in read

It seems better to replace the loop by

```
while((arr[i] == read()) != NULL)
   //printf("%s", arr[i]);  //DEBUG
   i += 1;
}
```

and to remove the preallocations of the lines

An other problem is when the file have more that 100 lines (or may be some lines are cut before too long), in that case you write out of *arr*. In fact you do not need to save so many lines, you just need to save 10 lines maximum

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read() {
  char line[80];

  if (fgets(line, 80, stdin) == NULL)
      return NULL;

   return strdup(line);
}

int main()
{
  char * arr[10] = { NULL };
  char * p;
  int i = 0, n = 0;

  while((p = read()) != NULL) {
    n += 1;
    free(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = p;
    if (++i == 10)
      i = 0;
  }

  /* get older line index and line count to print */
  if (n <= 10) 
    i = 0;
  else
    n = 10;

  while (n-- != 0) {
    puts(arr[i]);
    free(arr[i]);
    if (++i == 10)
      i = 0;
  }

   return 0;
}

Compilation and execution :
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra q.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ ./a.out < q.c
    n = 10;



  while (n-- != 0) {

    puts(arr[i]);

    if (++i == 10)

      i = 0;

  }



   return 0;

}
```

Note I do not removed the \n is the read lines and I use *puts* so there are empty lines printed while the read line are not cut because too long

If the file is shorter that 10 lines :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ tail -n 5 q.c | ./a.out
      i = 0;

  }



   return 0;

}
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ valgrind ./a.out < q.c
==18496== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18496== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18496== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18496== Command: ./a.out
==18496== 


  while (n-- != 0) {

    puts(arr[i]);

    free(arr[i]);

    if (++i == 10)

      i = 0;

  }



   return 0;

}

==18496== 
==18496== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18496==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18496==   total heap usage: 43 allocs, 43 frees, 5,699 bytes allocated
==18496== 
==18496== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18496== 
==18496== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18496== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```